# PHP multi dimension object attributes access from array

Tags: php, oop, object, iterator

I have an object which contain other objects.
I have an array that describes what is the attributes i need to access.
The Array can change in size.

My question is how can i access the sub-object attributes using the array?

Code example:

```
$student = new Student();
$arr = ['Grades', 'Score'];
foreach.... {}
```

expected result:

> $student->$arr[0]->$arr[1];

I need to iterate over the $arr and access the $student sub-object

Comment: I think you need a better example..

Comment: can you explain what is missing in the example?
There is a Student object which contain Grades object and that object has Score attribute.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you need a foreach then...

Comment: the thing is i dont know what is the object attributes in advance and the array might change in size...so i need to write a foreach loop that will access the object property..in an unknown array size

Comment: what if the items in that array are unordered respectively to object properties?

Comment: that object and the array has no relation?  Are they? if yes let me know. i am curious.

Comment: the object and the array has a relation and the array is ordered. like on the curiosity ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$student = new Student();
$sub_object = $student;  // or use $student itself if you don't need it
$arr = ['Grades', 'Score'];
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    $sub_object = $sub_object->$v;
}
echo $sub_object;
```

Comment: that is what i came to just this minute!! thx :)
BTW - i used reflactions just to make sure the attribute exist